# What happens if a question is deleted for old age and lack of response?

Tags: support, auto-delete

Say I made a question a year ago and it gets deleted for old age or lack of responses. Can I recover its content and if so for how long after such a deletion? Also is it possible to keep track of which questions do get deleted if one would want to save them for safe-keeping or something like that?

Comment: You can view your own deleted posts as long as you have a link to/the URL of the page.

Comment: To get a permanent link I *believe* it will suffice to favorite the question. It works for me, but it may be related to having 10k+. You could try it. Favorite one of your questions without answer. Save the link somewhere else too. Delete the question. Check if it still shows up under your favorites (with a red shade around). Undelete (going there from the favorites or if it does not work with the link saved elsewhere).    If you do test this. Could you please report the result.

Comment: This may be (sometimes) useful: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions-or-answers

Comment: @quid: Users below 10k don't see deleted favorite questions. But users above 10k do see deleted favorites of other users too. Which can be helpful in such case.

Comment: @Asaf Not even their own? (I mean their own deleted questions.)

Comment: @quid: Nope. I don't remember how I know this. But I know that I know that for a reason. (I think that before I was 10k on MathOverflow I had a favorite question that was also deleted; after hitting that barrier, I could see it again.)

Comment: @Asaf thanks for the confirmation. That feels somewhat inconsistent design-wise, but this is a different subject.

Comment: so after 10k all deleted questions become viewable?

Comment: There is this feature request related to what Asaf wrote: [User with less than 10K rep can add his own deleted question to favorites but can't see it listed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180008/user-with-less-than-10k-rep-can-add-his-own-deleted-question-to-favorites-but-ca). Perhaps some other related stuff can be found in meta.SE posts [tagged deleted-questions+favorites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted-questions+favorites).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Wonderful, thank you!